# How long does it take to microwave $n$ fish sticks?

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life

A box of fish sticks I bought at the store says it takes 2 minutes to heat up 5 of them in a 1000-watt microwave, and 3 minutes to heat up 10 of them.

I note that although the time required increases with the number of fish sticks, it increases less than proportionally.

What is a plausible mathematical model of how long it should to take to heat up $n$ fish sticks, and is the underlying physics of this well-established (experimentally or theoretically)?

I found a similar question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/387045/does-a-microwave-take-longer-to-heat-two-bowls-of-soup), but the only mathematically precise answer contradicts other answers there and the instructions on the package.

Comment: Well seeing as you have only two data points, you could find a *ton* of consistent mathematical models. You problem isn't well constrained.

Comment: @zhutchens1 You can make reasonable assumptions and introduce as many unknown constants as necessary. I'm interested in the general form of the function, not the specific values I gave. Those were to illustrate that the fish company thinks the function grows less than proportionally. I don't know what the physics would be, but I imagine it might need to be assumed that $n$ is small enough that a relatively small proportion of the space in the microwave is actually occupied by the fish sticks.

Comment: @Dave I think that the [math model based answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/387468/191954) in the link you mentioned is almost applicable here. You just need to include the fact that when you increase the number of fish sticks, you're decreasing the energy losses to the rest of the microwave. There's no easy way to mathematically model the change in energy loss, as far as I know. Hence when you double the number of fish sticks, you don't need to double the energy because less energy is lost in the first place.

Comment: @Chair Doesn't that answer say that the time is proportional to the mass of fish?

Comment: Yes, that answer indicates a direct proportion. But it ignores the fact that the heat loss is lower when you put 10 pieces of fish into the microwave, hence it's an approximation. That explains why when you double the amount of fish (increase by 100%), you need to increase the time by 50%, not 100%. That being said, as @zhutchens1 mentioned, with a lack of data points, we can't be sure that the package is correct, and the change in amount of energy lost is that big. We don't have enough input to create a good model of how the energy loss changes.

Comment: @Chair What information would be needed to model the heat loss? I'm asking not so much in terms of the data points provided ob the packaging, but in terms of the physical situation.

Comment: I do baked potatoes in a microwave. The rule of thumb is 5 minutes for each potato, and it works, they come out cooked ready for the butter. I have cooked up to 6 at a time in a bowl.  Now fish is more delicate, one should not overcook it, and that is why the rule of thumb is different.  There are too many variables for a fixed formula, they probably experimented with the size of the fish they offer.

Comment: @Dave Honestly, I don't know exactly what equations and input you'd need. Metals don't behave the same as fish sticks in a microwave. Fish have fat and moisture, so they absorb the radiation, but the interior of a microwave is designed to reflect it, so in an 'ideal' microwave I think the loss would be zero. Forget about modelling how the absorption by the microwave changes... It'd be hard enough to accurately model the energy absorbed by the microwave in just one case.